# error TS2348: Value of type 'typeof ObjectID' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?

Tags: angular, typescript, mongoose, typescript2.0

When I convert a `string` to `ObjectId`, I use

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const objId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(strId);
```

It works well in **TypeScript 1.x**, after updating to **TypeScript 2.x**, I got the error:

> error TS2348: Value of type 'typeof ObjectID' is not callable. Did you
>   mean to include 'new'?

How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: How about using `new`? Should be as simple as: `const objId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(strId);`

Comment: @NitzanTomer Wow, I remembered I tried it before but failed, but now it works well! Would u mind moving to answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The mongoose docs show that you can instantiate `ObjectId` without the `new` keyword, but the typescript definitions (at least the ones I've seen, like [the one on DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8833261722781ea724f5cfcc50a1f1c757f8295b/types/mongoose/index.d.ts#L1937)) don't have that, so if you want to avoid typescript compilation errors you'll need to use the `new` keyword:

```
const objId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(strId);
```

You should also be able to do something like:

```
type ObjectIdConstructor = {
    (str: string): mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
    new (str: string): mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
}

const objId = (mongoose.Types.ObjectId as ObjectIdConstructor)(strId);
```

Comment: Link is broken.